# Process another input in same datatable row along with <p:fileUpload auto="true">

Tags: jsf, file-upload, primefaces, datatable, selectonemenu

My primefaces upload code does not process the value selected from my dropdown. Heres the code for my primefaces upload:

```
<h:form id="frmUpload" enctype="multipart/form-data">  

       <p:column><h:outputText value="Select Team: " /></p:column>
        <p:column>
                #{' '}
                <h:selectOneMenu required="true" id="ddlTeam" value="#{telesalesUpload.searchTeam}">
                <f:selectItem itemValue="1" itemLabel="SAVD Team"  />
                <f:selectItem itemValue="0" itemLabel="Dunning Team Team" />
                </h:selectOneMenu>
                #{' '}
    </p:column>

<h:outputText value="Note: first row will be skipped as header row!" />  
<p:fileUpload  fileUploadListener="#{telesalesUpload.handleFileUpload}"  
        auto="true"
        mode="advanced"
        update="messages,:frmData"  

        allowTypes="/(\.|\/)(csv|jpe?g|png)$/" process = "@this,ddlTeam" />  
<p:growl id="messages" showDetail="true"/>
```

I want my uploader to process the value "ddlTeam". "searchTeam" is a string which is set as "1", as the default value, in the bean.

Comment: You are using PrimeFaces though are you interested in `<h:selectOneMenu>` thus, not `<p:selectOneMenu>`? Try looking into the generated HTML code, the value of `id` of `<h:selectOneMenu>` will be prepending according to container components' `id` along with a repeating row index (of `<p:dataTable>`).  You need to mention the correct value of that `id` in the `process` attribute of `<p:fileUpload>` accordingly, if you want to get that component (`<h:selectOneMenu>`) to be processed/executed.

Comment: This is the correct id. ddlTeam is the correct id of the menu. It is mentioned in my code.

Comment: Did you leave this comment after looking into the generated HTML source code? If the stated `<h:selectOneMenu>` was wrapped in an iterating JSF/PrimeFaces component like `<p/h:dataTable>`, `<p:dataList>`, `<p:dataGrid>`, the value of the generated `id`  would be different. Please do not just guess, if you are not sure about the generated `id`. It would look something like this `frmUpload:dataTable:0:ddlTeam` where `frmUpload` is an `id` of `<h:form>`,  `dataTable` is an `id` of `<p/h:dataTable>`, `0` is a repeating row index of `<p:dataTable>` and `ddlTeam` is an `id`  of `<h:selectOneMenu>`.

Comment: Please bother to have a look into the generated HTML source code for the correct value of the `id`, if the given `<h:selectOneMenu>` was wrapped in an iterating component and adjust your code to get it to be processed by the given `<p:fileUpload>`.